# Is there any specific API to verify the purchase information of PAID APPS made directly by PLAY STORE?

Tags: java, google-api, google-play, in-app-billing

Is there any way to verify **DATE OF PURCHASE** and which **USER ACCOUNT** was used in the **PLAY STORE** when purchasing a **PAID APPLICATION**?

**in-app Billing API** offers features for checking **product purchase** information and **subscriptions**, but I have not found anything about **paid apps**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [license verification library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html). It doesn't give you user account and date in the same way, but gives you enough information to check the app was purchased.

Almost all incompatible devices will because of things in your device manifest. If you want more advice from Stack Overflow, then you'll need to post your `ApkManifest.xml` in your question.

Comment: Thank for your help, but i´m already using lvl. I really need the date of app purchase to force users to buy subscriptions over a paid app.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: I need the application purchase date to check how long each user has the app installed.

Comment: This doesn't exist, and I suspect is unlikely to ever exist. Play's model is any user who paid for the app should get the same privileges regardless of when they bought it